# Javascript Array from AJAX file

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays

I'm having issues with getting data from an AJAX file,

I am trying to change the datasource of a web app and the data source is originally created like this in javascript:

```
var ds = [
'Sarah',
'John',
'Jack',
'Don',
'Ben',
'Breem'];
```

Instead of hard-coding it in like this, I wanted to get it from an ajax file, and I have tried to do this:

```
    var categories = $.ajax({
  url: "js/ajax.php?projects=1",
  async: false
 }).responseText;
```

But it seems to be interpretting every character as a segment in the array, I tested with the exact same array and just echoed

```
[
'Sarah',
'John',
'Jack',
'Don',
'Ben',
'Breem']
```

I think I need to return it as an array, but I'm not sure how, should I be using like getJSON for this? Thanks!

UPDATE: I have managed to make it understand it as an array by surrounding the request with eval(), is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UPDATE: I have managed to make it
>   understand it as an array by
>   surrounding the request with eval(),
>   is this the right way to do it?

Yes, that's the right way. Otherwise you will just get a string and since a string is basically an array of charcters, that's what you see.